# Can I pass simple string parameters to JS method?

Tags: javascript, html

I m trying to pass a simple string parameter to a method.
I googled but they are not showing anything relative.
I don't know where i am doing a mistake. Here is my JavaScript and HTML code for the same.

```
function check(var tyt) {
    document.getElementById(""+tyt).checked="checked";
}
```

Here is my html code:

```
<input type=radio name="InterestedIn" id="Placement" required value="Placement" /><font onClick="check('Placement')">Placement</font>
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support type-hinting on method parameters, which you may have experience of using in other languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// without the 'var' in parameter list:
function check(tyt) {
  document.getElementById("" + tyt).checked = "checked";
}
```

And for your HTML, you can achive this without JavaScript:

```
<label>
  <input type=radio name="InterestedIn" id="Placement" required value="Placement" />
  Placement 
</label>
```

And one more thing: `<font>`-Tag is deprecated since 1960 or so. :)

However there is a littel difference between your `onclick` which will only check the checkbox and the `<label>` which will also uncheck the box when clicked again.

Comment: @RahulGoel It's true, don't use `font` tag ;)